# Замена текста на рандомное число. Notepad++

Tags: регулярные-выражения, текст, notepad++, замена

Как заменить в тексте слово "**CARBONTO**" (оно повторяется несколько раз в тексте) на любое число. То есть каждый раз слово "**CARBONTO**" будет заменено на какое-либо число (не повторяющееся до этого)

*Длинна числа - до 6-ти символов (пример:от 1 - 167549)*

пример текста (малая часть текста):
*"...текст  текст **CARBONTO** текст, текст **CARBONTO** текст, текст **CARBONTO**...."*

Comment: Продемонстрируйте, пожалуйста, ваши попытки реализовать желаемое! Иначе, вы похожи на человека, которому кто-то, что-то, должен сделать за него!

Comment: а notepad++ умеет генерировать случайные числа? Это проще сделать, например, на C# с использованием `MatchEvaluator`

Comment: Это можно реализовать с помощью PythonScript. Начните, попробуйте свои силы, опишите, что не получается, поможем.